# Java Graphics.drawString() font as JLabel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts, jlabel

How to make `Graphics.drawString()` get exactly the same font as that of `JLabel`?

I've tried all the fonts I could find in  `UIManager.getDefaults()` but even if I use the followings to make the String that drawString() not that thin as before.

```
((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

It still looks a little bit different.

Comment: no easy and no complete way (assuming the question is how to get the same antialising behaviour in a g.drawString as in JLabel has internally :-) - the usual work around that is to _not_ use g.drawString, but instead use a JLabel configured with the text, make that draw itself into a bufferedImage and draw the image. Or use a CellRendererPane which stamps the label onto the required location/size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIManager.getFont("Label.font")` should work under most look & feels

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer. But even with that font, the output of a Graphics.drawString() is not the same as a normal JLabel

Comment: Can I assume that your call `g.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font")` ??

Comment: Yes, sure it was. It seems that java draw JLabel has some differences from Graphics.drawString();

Comment: @Xmagic you "could" spend some time reading through the `BasicLabelUI` and `SwingUtilities` class, but in the short term, kleopatra's suggestion will solve your problem more quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I fixed it!! I went through 'BasicLabelUI' and find the code used to be displayed the JLabel.        Use `SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt()` instead of using `Graphics.drawString()`

Comment: @Xmagic just keep in mind that classes under the sun packages are restricted api that a) cannot be used in the sandbox b) has no guarantee to be stable c) is not available in jres from other vendors. If you can live with those - nice dig :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about `new JLabel().getFont()`?